# Message sent to Topic not forwarded by ActiveMQ

Tags: apache, activemq-classic, broker

Just wondering if anyone has come across this problem with ActiveMQ.

I am using network of brokers to forward messages using AMQ 5.11.0

```
<networkConnectors>
    <networkConnector name="linkToBrokerB" uri="static (tcp://(brokerAddress):61616)">
    <dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
        <queue physicalName="QueueName"/> 
        <topic physicalName="VirtualTopic.Message.Event.EventName"/> 
    </dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
</networkConnector>
```

when I queue a message on broker A it gets forwarded to broker B respective queue using the configuration above. However, it does not work for topics. When I send a topic to broker A it does not get forwarded to broker B Topic. I have a consumer on both brokers listening to that respective topic. If I try to forward messages using one or more queues it works without any issues, but I cannot figure out why it does not work for topics.

I tried using the ">" but it does not forward anything. I can see that the topic has a consumer and that broker B is connected to broker A in the "network" tab but it does not forward my topic as it does with my queues. I have also checked that the physical name used in the configuration is the same one as it appears under "topics" category

Any help would be appreciated